# Exception ZF2 Doctrine2 Too many connections?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

plz i'm facing here a problem ; using doctrine 2 zf2 when there 's many connections it throws this exception ; the problem is not about the excpetion but about that it showing up the login and the password of the DB ... how can i fix it , how can i at least avoid showing the password and the login? thanks.

[image]

Comment: Which version of php are you using? Howenever try increase the max connection of mysql launching from the mysql console the command `set global max_connections = 800;` . Hope this help

Comment: i'm using php version 5.2.0

Answer (score 1):

If you're in development, this kind of information is useful. However, if you're in production, you should avoid outputting this kind of errors. Modify your `php.ini` configuration as soon as possible setting `display_errors = off`

Also try to catch exceptions and handle them using try/catch blocks in your code.

**UPDATE**

If you have `display_errors = off` in your `php.ini` and the errors are still showing up, it could be possible that you were overriding that clause somewhere in your code using `ini_set` sentences or that you're using another `php.ini` file (there could be more than one).

If you are in production, you'll have to remove those `ini_set` or override them again using the sentence `ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');` where suitable.

Those are PDO exceptions and the message isn't something you can modify so the only way to avoid this problem is to capture exceptions or to avoid showing them turning off the `display_errors` thing.

Comment: i'm in production , and the php.ini is configured with display_errors = off ...!!!!

Comment: @user3911183 are you overriding your php.ini in your code using `ini_set` sentences?

Comment: thanks for your reply , the problem is that i can't reproduct the error , so i think that i should find how  to catch the exceptions in general way...